# AppleScript: File that exists not found

Tags: applescript, filepath

My applescript is telling me that the file I'm trying to get is not found. But it's right here, I can open it using the exact same path in the terminal.
Here is a simplified version of the code that gives the same error:

```
set theFile to "~/Desktop/MyFile.csv" as alias
set theContent to read theFile as «class utf8»
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path string is incorrect for applescript. It's expecting an HFS path like this...
Path:to:my:file:MyFile.csv, not a POSIX path.

I would recommend doing something like this...

```
set theFile to ((path to desktop folder as string) & "MyFile.csv") as alias
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That would solve what I posted, however what I'm hiding in the code I gave is that the script is actually getting that full path as a string from an input from a program. Do I have to do something like setting the text item delimiters to "/", reading the string, setting the delimiters to ":" and saving the string again? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: I just realized what I described wouldn't work. Can AppleScript really not handle POSIX paths?

Comment: You can convert a POSIX path in applescript to an HFS path like this... `set thePath to POSIX file yourPOSIXpath as Unicode text` but you're using the shortened version of the POSIX path, I'm doubtful this method will convert it.

Comment: Ok, I have a working solution for you....

`set theFullPOSIXPath to do shell script "echo ~/Desktop/Myfile.txt"` then

`set theHFSPath to POSIX file theFullPOSIXPath as Unicode text`